# remove . from the results of find

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg

I am trying to use the below command on ubuntu to find files in one folder and feed through FFmpeg and output to another folder. The problem is that when it processes the output path and filename it adds a . to the path like so: /conversions./resultFromFind.mkv

```
find -name '*720p*.mp4' -exec ffmpeg -i {} -c:v copy -c:a ac3 /home/plex/library/localFiles/Complete/conversions{} \;
```

I understand why it does that but can't find the right search term to get a solution. How do I remove the . ?

Comment: just add an extra slash: `/home/plex/library/localFiles/Complete/conversions/{}`?

Comment: The / was left off of my example because the {} adds the ./ to the begin of the name. I either need the find result to come back minus just the . or the ./ so its just the name.

Answer (score 0):

Using pwd should get you what you need.

```
find `pwd` -name '720p.mp4' -exec ffmpeg -i {} -c:v copy -c:a ac3 /home/plex/library/localFiles/Complete/conversions{} \;
```

Comment: This option worked but not the results i needed. It takes the full path starting with /home/user/ so when i send the {} to the output it wants to send it to /home/plex/library/localFiles/Complete/conversions/home/plex/library/localFiles/Complete/manual/movies/tmp/ I need for only the filename or minus the . not including the path.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
dest=/home/plex/library/localFiles/Complete/conversions
find -type f -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file_name; do
    ffmpeg -i "$file_name" -c:v copy -c:a ac3 "$dest"/"${file_name#.}"
done
```

> ${string#substring}
>   Deletes shortest match of $substring from front of $string.

[Source](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) -> section "Substring Removal":

*(The `/` between `$dest` and `${file_name#.}` is not necessary, I put it for readability).*